# Meaning of "it come down to" in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the phrase "it comes down to" in this dialogue:

> A: Help me with my homework, please.
>
> B: ARGH!So this is what **it comes down to**

I have looked this up in the dictionary but all the meanings are seemingly incorrect.

Comment: Probable duplicate: [Confused by “comes down to” and similar phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260426/confused-by-comes-down-to-and-similar-phrases). But answers there not totally applicable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific example:

> B: ARGH! So this is what it come**s** down to

I have added an 's' to 'come' because 'come down to' is not grammatically correct.

In this specific case, what student B is really saying is:

> B: Oh, of course this conversation is about me helping you with your homework.

or

> B: Oh, so that's why you're talking to me.

Basically, B is annoyed that they are being asked to help with A's homework. Perhaps B thought A was talking to them because they're friends. Perhaps B thought A would be doing their own work.

It could also mean other things, but we would need more of the conversation in order to know that. With the snippets you have provided, this is what I would guess.

In general, "comes down to" implies the reasoning for something happening. You can also say "boils down to", which would mean the same thing. When you boil a liquid, the condensed solid left behind is a pure, strong form of whatever it was which was being boiled. Therefore the saying "comes/boils down to" implies that this [the subject] is the core issue of what it [the action] is about. This may have been hidden, for example in the conversation in which A asks for B's help with the homework, when B may have thought A was talking to B for a different purpose.

Comment: This is the same answer as one of those given at the duplicate. Here' there's the connotation (at least) of 'down to new depths' (so this is what we've come to) as well as 'down to basics'.